# Exibir imagem dentro da div

Tags: css, css3

Tenho uma div uma imagem.
Seria necessário exibir parte da imagem (centralizada, por exemplo) e diminuir o tamanho da div.

Se eu der um overflow hidden com width de 50% em alguma div acima da imagem, funciona, mas fica um buraco que não alinha o outro lado.

Seria possível diminuir a div sem diminuir a imagem?

Essa é a ideia original:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

E isso o que perguntei:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```css
.news-section .slide-item.right-margin {
  margin-right: 13px;
}

.news-section .slide-item.column-margin {
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 40px;
}

.news-section .slide-item .image-box {
  position: relative;
  display: table-cell;
}

figure {
  margin: 0;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: #2681c3;
}

.news-section .slide-item .image-box img {
  border-radius: 5px;
}

.news-section .slide-item .image-box:after {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  bottom: 0px;
  content: '';
  border-radius: 5px;
  /* background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3); */
}

.news-section .slide-item .date-box {
  position: absolute;
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  right: 30px;
  top: 40px;
  background: #2681c3;
  z-index: 9;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

.news-section .slide-item .date-box h5 {
  font-size: 27px;
  font-family: 'Larsseit-Bold';
  line-height: 20px;
  color: #ffffff;
  margin-top: 10px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.news-section .slide-item .date-box h5:before {
  color: #2681c3;
  content: "\f0da";
  font-family: FontAwesome;
  position: absolute;
  right: -8px;
  top: 10px;
  transition: all 500ms ease;
  -moz-transition: all 500ms ease;
  -webkit-transition: all 500ms ease;
  -ms-transition: all 500ms ease;
  -o-transition: all 500ms ease;
}

.news-section .slide-item .date-box h5 span {
  font-size: 15px;
  font-family: 'Larsseit-Thin';
  color: #ffffff;
}

.news-section .slide-item .inner-box {
  position: relative;
  display: table-cell;
  left: -20px;
  vertical-align: top;
  padding-top: 24px;
}

.news-section .slide-item .inner-box .info-outer {
  position: relative;
  /* padding: 30px 16px; */
  margin-right: -20px;
}

.corpo_blog {
  padding: 16px 16px 30px 16px;
  background: #ffffff;
  border-radius: 5px;
  border: 1px solid #e5e5e5;
}

.news-section .slide-item .inner-box .info-outer h5 {
  font-size: 20px;
  /* color: #2e2e2e; */
  letter-spacing: .5px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-family: 'Larsseit-Bold';
  text-align: initial;
  display: -webkit-box;
  height: 44px;
  line-height: 22px;
  -webkit-line-clamp: 2;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}

.cor_titulos {
  color: #2e2e2e;
}

.news-section .inner-box .info-outer .link-btn {
  margin-top: 48px;
  text-align: right;
}

.news-section .inner-box .info-outer .link-btn a {
  line-height: 24px;
  text-transform: capitalize;
  transition: all 500ms ease;
  letter-spacing: .5px;
  font-family: 'Larsseit-Bold';
  font-size: 15px;
  text-align: right;
  color: #2681c3;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.news-section .inner-box .info-outer h6 {
  font-size: 17px;
  /* color: #2e2e2e; */
  margin-top: 10px;
  font-family: 'Larsseit-Light';
  text-align: initial;
  display: -webkit-box;
  height: 88px;
  line-height: 22px;
  -webkit-line-clamp: 4;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-WskhaSGFgHYWDcbwN70/dfYBj47jz9qbsMId/iRN3ewGhXQFZCSftd1LZCfmhktB" crossorigin="anonymous">


<div class="news-section style-two">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
      <div class="slide-item column-margin right-margin">
        <div class="image-box figure_box">
          <figure class="figure_blog">
            <a href="#"><img src="https://files.incrivel.club/files/news/part_40/405910/preview-13524560-650x341-98-1519527991.jpg" alt=""></a>
          </figure>
          <div class="date-box text-center">
            <h5>03<br><span>Jul</span></h5>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="inner-box">
          <div class="info-outer">
            <a href="#">
              <div class="corpo_blog">
                <h5 class="cor_titulos">Carga de pneus avaliada em cerca de R$ 500 mil é recuperada pela PRF/AL</h5>
                <h6 class="cor_titulos">Um caminhão com carga avaliada em aproximadamente R$ 500 mil foi recuperado pela Polícia Rodoviária Federal (PRF/AL) na madrugada desta sexta-feira (29), nas proximidades do km 84 da BR-101, entrada da Empresa Britex Minerações, no município
                  de Rio Largo/AL. Segundo a PRF, houve intensa troca de tiros com os suspeitos que estavam com a carga, mas ninguém ficou ferido.Ainda de acordo com a polícia, a denúncia chegou através da Central de Informações, que recebeu uma ligação
                  da Empresa de Rastreamento informando que havia perdido o sinal de rastreamento de um dos seus veículos. Ao receberem a informação, as equipes se deslocaram para averiguação.Ao chegarem ao local, o caminhão estava com as portas abertas,
                  o motorista sendo mantido refém por um indivíduo armado e outros retirando a carga do veículo. Quando perceberem a chegada das viaturas, os assaltantes começaram a efetuar disparos de arma de fogo em direção aos policiais, que revidaram
                  a agressão. Após a troca de tiros, os assaltantes fugiram em direção a um matagal.O motorista do caminhão informou à polícia que foi rendido por três homens armados em um posto de combustível localizado às margens da BR-101, no município
                  de Messias/AL. Ele informou ainda que, na ocasião, havia outro veículo dando cobertura.A mercadoria que estava sendo transportada - cerca de 550 pneus - foi recuperada intacta. Além disso, um aparelho utilizado pelos assaltantes para
                  bloquear o sinal de rastreamento do veículo foi apreendido pelos policiais. O veículo recuperado e o aparelho apreendido, bem como a vítima, um senhor de 56 anos, foram encaminhados à Delegacia de Roubos e Furtos de veículos em Maceió.</h6>
              </div>
            </a>
            <div class="link-btn">
              <a href="#">saiba mais</a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Rogério pelo relato esta meio difpicil de entender o que realmente vc precisa. Teria como vc editar a pergunta com uma imagem de como está e de como vc gostaria que ficasse?

Comment: Sim, vou fazer uma simulação.

Comment: Agora ficou um pouco mais claro, só mais uma coisa, o que vc quer dizer com "um buraco que não alinha o outro lado." o que seria esse buraco e o que deve alinhar onde?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rogério pelo que entendi é que quando vc coloca a imagem menor fica um espaço em brando entre a imagem e o box com a informação correto? Se for isso acho que esse css abaixo pode te ajudar.

Mas independente disso vc vai ter que pensar bem nessa estrutura para ela funcionar de forma responsiva direito. Vc poderia ter usado `display:flex` em vez de colocar `display:table-cell` que acredito estar dificultando as coisas...

O modelo que fiz foi tipo pegando a tag `<figure>` e colocando nela uma largura em PX (só consegui fazer funcionar assim para mexer o mínimo possível no seu css) com o `Overflow:hidden`. Também coloquei um `transform:translateX(-25%)` pra vc controlar qual parte da imagem vai querer mostrar.

```css
     .news-section .slide-item.right-margin {
      margin-right: 13px;
    }
    
    .news-section .slide-item.column-margin {
      padding-top: 10px;
      padding-bottom: 40px;
    }
    
    .news-section .slide-item .image-box {
      position: relative;
      display: table-cell;
    }
    
    figure {
      margin: 0;
    }
    
    a {
      text-decoration: none;
      cursor: pointer;
      color: #2681c3;
    }
    
    .news-section .slide-item .image-box img {
      border-radius: 5px;
    }
    
    .news-section .slide-item .image-box:after {
      position: absolute;
      top: 0px;
      left: 0px;
      right: 0px;
      bottom: 0px;
      content: '';
      border-radius: 5px;
      /* background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3); */
    }
    
    .news-section .slide-item .date-box {
      position: absolute;
      width: 60px;
      height: 60px;
      right: 30px;
      top: 40px;
      background: #2681c3;
      z-index: 9;
      border-radius: 5px;
    }
    
    .news-section .slide-item .date-box h5 {
      font-size: 27px;
      font-family: 'Larsseit-Bold';
      line-height: 20px;
      color: #ffffff;
      margin-top: 10px;
      text-transform: uppercase;
    }
    
    .news-section .slide-item .date-box h5:before {
      color: #2681c3;
      content: "\f0da";
      font-family: FontAwesome;
      position: absolute;
      right: -8px;
      top: 10px;
      transition: all 500ms ease;
      -moz-transition: all 500ms ease;
      -webkit-transition: all 500ms ease;
      -ms-transition: all 500ms ease;
      -o-transition: all 500ms ease;
    }
    
    .news-section .slide-item .date-box h5 span {
      font-size: 15px;
      font-family: 'Larsseit-Thin';
      color: #ffffff;
    }
    
    .news-section .slide-item .inner-box {
      position: relative;
      display: table-cell;
      left: -20px;
      vertical-align: top;
      padding-top: 24px;
    }
    
    .news-section .slide-item .inner-box .info-outer {
      position: relative;
      /* padding: 30px 16px; */
      margin-right: -20px;
    }
    
    .corpo_blog {
      padding: 16px 16px 30px 16px;
      background: #ffffff;
      border-radius: 5px;
      border: 1px solid #e5e5e5;
    }
    
    .news-section .slide-item .inner-box .info-outer h5 {
      font-size: 20px;
      /* color: #2e2e2e; */
      letter-spacing: .5px;
      text-transform: uppercase;
      font-family: 'Larsseit-Bold';
      text-align: initial;
      display: -webkit-box;
      height: 44px;
      line-height: 22px;
      -webkit-line-clamp: 2;
      -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
      overflow: hidden;
      text-overflow: ellipsis;
    }
    
    .cor_titulos {
      color: #2e2e2e;
    }
    
    .news-section .inner-box .info-outer .link-btn {
      margin-top: 48px;
      text-align: right;
    }
    
    .news-section .inner-box .info-outer .link-btn a {
      line-height: 24px;
      text-transform: capitalize;
      transition: all 500ms ease;
      letter-spacing: .5px;
      font-family: 'Larsseit-Bold';
      font-size: 15px;
      text-align: right;
      color: #2681c3;
      text-transform: uppercase;
    }
    
    .news-section .inner-box .info-outer h6 {
      font-size: 17px;
      /* color: #2e2e2e; */
      margin-top: 10px;
      font-family: 'Larsseit-Light';
      text-align: initial;
      display: -webkit-box;
      height: 88px;
      line-height: 22px;
      -webkit-line-clamp: 4;
      -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
      overflow: hidden;
      text-overflow: ellipsis;
    }
    figure {
      max-width: 325px;
      overflow: hidden;
    }
    figure a img {
      transform: translateX(-25%);
    }
```

```html
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
  
  <div class="news-section style-two">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
          <div class="slide-item column-margin right-margin">
            <div class="image-box figure_box">
              <figure class="figure_blog">
                <a href="#"><img src="https://files.incrivel.club/files/news/part_40/405910/preview-13524560-650x341-98-1519527991.jpg" alt=""></a>
              </figure>
              <div class="date-box text-center">
                <h5>03<br><span>Jul</span></h5>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="inner-box">
              <div class="info-outer">
                <a href="#">
                  <div class="corpo_blog">
                    <h5 class="cor_titulos">Carga de pneus avaliada em cerca de R$ 500 mil é recuperada pela PRF/AL</h5>
                    <h6 class="cor_titulos">Um caminhão com carga avaliada em aproximadamente R$ 500 mil foi recuperado pela Polícia Rodoviária Federal (PRF/AL) na madrugada desta sexta-feira (29), nas proximidades do km 84 da BR-101, entrada da Empresa Britex Minerações, no município
                      de Rio Largo/AL. Segundo a PRF, houve intensa troca de tiros com os suspeitos que estavam com a carga, mas ninguém ficou ferido.Ainda de acordo com a polícia, a denúncia chegou através da Central de Informações, que recebeu uma ligação
                      da Empresa de Rastreamento informando que havia perdido o sinal de rastreamento de um dos seus veículos. Ao receberem a informação, as equipes se deslocaram para averiguação.Ao chegarem ao local, o caminhão estava com as portas abertas,
                      o motorista sendo mantido refém por um indivíduo armado e outros retirando a carga do veículo. Quando perceberem a chegada das viaturas, os assaltantes começaram a efetuar disparos de arma de fogo em direção aos policiais, que revidaram
                      a agressão. Após a troca de tiros, os assaltantes fugiram em direção a um matagal.O motorista do caminhão informou à polícia que foi rendido por três homens armados em um posto de combustível localizado às margens da BR-101, no município
                      de Messias/AL. Ele informou ainda que, na ocasião, havia outro veículo dando cobertura.A mercadoria que estava sendo transportada - cerca de 550 pneus - foi recuperada intacta. Além disso, um aparelho utilizado pelos assaltantes para
                      bloquear o sinal de rastreamento do veículo foi apreendido pelos policiais. O veículo recuperado e o aparelho apreendido, bem como a vítima, um senhor de 56 anos, foram encaminhados à Delegacia de Roubos e Furtos de veículos em Maceió.</h6>
                  </div>
                </a>
                <div class="link-btn">
                  <a href="#">saiba mais</a>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: É exatamente isso que eu precisava. Aprendendo mais uma! Nas classes responsivas vou ter que fazer em várias escalas, mas tudo bem nesse caso.

Comment: @RogérioPancini infelizmente vc vai precisar tratar com @-medias sim, pois o valor está em px, mas não se preocupe esse tipo de refinamento é comum em qualquer site. Boa sorte com o projeto, vc está no caminho certo, a maioria em vez de fazer na mão já procura algo pronto e acaba não aprendendo direito. Boa sorte